# Can i detect Vim macro recording mode from Vim script function, and call this function in Vim macro recording mode?

Tags: macros, vim

I would like to make a custom single-key Vim mapping that could be used both to start recording a macro to the unnamed register (`q"`) and to stop recording a macro (`q`).

Can i detect from Vim script if Vim is in recording mode?

If detecting recording mode is possible, will there be any problems if my function will be evoked in the recording mode (to stop recording)?  I mean, can it happen that the function call will be recorded inside the macro?

Comment: Hey Vimmers, does anybody know the answer, or what?

Comment: Can you give an example test case? Since it just takes two keystrokes, why would you need a macro?

Comment: @SibiCoder i wanted to use the same key to start and to stop recording.

Comment: I think you can use operator pending mode to map. (While stopping, it won't wait for other key. But while starting it waits)

Comment: You can map `q"` with any key. While starting it will work. While stopping, it presses q", (that is an extra quote). As far as I know, none of the commands start with `"`. So , it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't recommend this, since starting recording is only two
keypresses, and you get the flexibility of selecting a register.

That said, here's how you could do it. I don't know a way to directly
detect recording mode, but you can create a mapping that will remap
itself on each keypress, thus alternating between starting and stopping
recording:

```
" Helper mappings
nnoremap @{ :nmap ; @}<CR>qq
nnoremap @} q:nmap ; @{<CR>

" Toggle recording
nmap ; @{

" Playback
nnoremap , @q
```

Pick your own keys to map, as suit you best.

Also, I don't recommend using `"` for the recording register: it's too
easily overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use mapping to `q"<esc>`. Assuming that you start recording only when you are in normal mode (and `insertmode` is not set), this would do just what you want.